# KeepScreenOnRequest.RequestActive Not Working

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

For my Windows Store App, I want my application to be active all the time.

I am using code below. My Device set to be go into screen lock in 10 seconds, while I am using my application it still goes into lock screen. Am I using this code incorrectly?

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    // Prevent tablet from sleeping while app is running
    Windows.System.Display.DisplayRequest KeepScreenOnRequest = new Windows.System.Display.DisplayRequest();
    KeepScreenOnRequest.RequestActive();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should try it on page navigation events instead of application level events...

```
using Windows.System.Display;

private DisplayRequest KeepScreenOnRequest;

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    if(KeepScreenOnRequest == null)
        KeepScreenOnRequest = new DisplayRequest();

    KeepScreenOnRequest.RequestActive();
}

protected override void OnNavigatingFrom(NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatingFrom(e);

    KeepScreenOnRequest.RequestRelease();
}
```

Again in this scenario you have to handle the request and release part on all of your app's pages individually...

Comment: Great approach, thanks for info. Weird not mentioned in their documentation.

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem may be elsewhere - your *DisplayRequest* may be garbage collected. Try like this:

```cs
Windows.System.Display.DisplayRequest KeepScreenOnRequest;

protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    KeepScreenOnRequest = new Windows.System.Display.DisplayRequest();
    // Prevent tablet from sleeping while app is running
    KeepScreenOnRequest.RequestActive();
}
```

Few notes:

- of course the above code should work for the whole app, when not needed - release the request
- putting this in *OnNavigatedFrom/OnNavigatedTo* may not be a good idea, unless handeled properly - for example when app is suspended (common case) after you return *OnNavigated* won't be called - your *DisplayRequest* probably won't be activated
- you don't need to worry about releasing you request while the app goes to background, [as mentioned at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj152728.aspx):

  > Note  Windows automatically deactivates your app's active display requests when it is moved off screen, and re-activates them when your app comes back to the foreground.